# why does mysql update erases field data?

Tags: mysql

mysql update deletes the field data on some rows rather than update them when i run this mysql statement

```
 UPDATE
    tablename
SET
    date = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I am trying to update date formats from 05/08/2013 to 2013-05-08 to make it so I can search where date between $date and $date

Comment: What's the data type of the column `date` and the value in the fields it will delete _before_ the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET `date` = STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

and then change the datatype of the column like this

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE COLUMN `date` `date` DATE
```

OR ALternatively

```
update tablename SET date = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d/%m/%y'),'%y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: @Breezy I am glad it helped...and if this is the correct answer please choose it as your answer for this question :)

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your `date` field is true `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatype. After that,

```
UPDATE tablename
SET `date` = STR_TO_DATE(old_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Then, you would be able to do all normal math on dates: add, subtract, compare, sort, etc.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL STR_TO_DATE() returns a datetime value by taking a string and a specific format string as arguments.

If the date or time or datetime value specified as string is illegal, the function returns NULL so check all value in select statement first to know if its returning null

```
 Select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y-%m-%d") from tablename
```